# Android: call the filesystem explorer

Tags: android, filesystems

I was trying to call the default filesystem explorer or any other installed filesystem or cloud explorer.

I wrote this code:

```
 // code
final int ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE = 1;
 //code
  onClick // other stuff
  Intent chooseFile;
        Intent intent;
        chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        chooseFile.setType("file/png");
        intent = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
        startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE);
   //end onClick
```

and

```
     @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode) {
          case ACTIVITY_CHOOSE_FILE: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
              Uri uri = data.getData();
              String filePath = uri.getPath();


            }
```

But, for example, he doesn't show "MyFiles" or other filesystem explorers, but only "Dropbox" and "Drive".

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's going to open up a dialog to select which file browser to use (believe it or not, not every android device has a file browser by default).  Some of these will have extra abilities (such as Dropbox being able to browse files on the server).  Android will list every installed app that claims to be able to handle ACTION_GET_CONTENT on that mime type.  If apps aren't showing up, either they aren't installed on that device, they don't handle that intent, or they don't handle that MIME type.